# Papers in progress, but am leaving academia

Tags: authorship

What should I do with my papers in progress? I have several with a few co-authors.  It's been known that things in my department have deteriorated considerably, and that many of the newer faculty are looking to leave.

Do my papers in progress get abandoned?

Comment: Do you have time and do you want to complete them? Do your coauthors want them completed? Can they complete them on their own?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If somebody puts an effort into them, they will potentially get submitted and published. If not, then not. No magic.

Comment: I don't understand the restriction that your leaving has with finishing (or even beginning) a paper. Is there something subject-specific that prevents work being done by email (or postal mail, for that matter)? The fact that you're leaving academia also seems irrelevant, unless your new job has insane hours (like 80+ hours a week), leaving you no time in early mornings or late evenings (depending on your sleep hours) and weekends to work on the papers.

Comment: @daveLrenfro It's mostly an employee morale issue, I suppose.  Finishing those papers would seem to benefit the department more so than me, and we've not been treated well during the pandemic. There are also experiments involved but they're mostly done.  It's the manuscripts that are in progress.  Just looking for a voice of reason.  Maybe I'll hate industry and seek to return to academia?

Comment: Hmmm. Finishing paper benefits the authors, not the department. Don't quit as a spiteful move that harms yourself more than anyone else.

Comment: Personally, I would try to finish them because you never know what the future holds, and this isn't something you're likely going to be able to do several years from now (or at least, not as easily). Of course, it also depends on how much work you've invested so far and how significant the results are -- hardly any work by you and easily forgotten and probably no one cares results would merit maybe not worrying about. Maybe prioritize away (i.e. stop work) on those like I just described, since there are several papers. But as Buffy just said, the papers benefit you a lot more than the dept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can complete the papers and should if your co-authors would be disadvantaged by your quitting, assuming that it is possible.

But, a fair amount of work gets abandoned, or put on the back shelf for various reasons. If you really don't have the time to continue work on the paper(s) come to an agreement with your co-authors that permits them to continue without you. The agreement should include something about authorship, but definitely should include your permission to publish.

If you all agree to abandon the work, put it in a notebook that you might want to return to later after things settle down. You can't predict the future and should keep flexible and ready for changes.

Your statements in comments seem to imply that you are angry with the department. That is natural, but don't take actions that primarily disadvantage yourself or the colleagues you work with. "Don't cut off your nose to spite your face" is an old adage.

Answer (score 5):

They're still your papers (unless your institution has very unusual and draconian IP policies), and they will "get abandoned" if, and only if, you choose to abandon them.  You'll have to decide for yourself what to do about those projects, based on what is of value to you and to people you care about.  If you want to keep working on them on your own time (or as part of your new job), you can certainly do so.

Things you could consider:

- Is the project intellectually interesting to you?
- Will you still have the resources (equipment, funding, etc) that you would need to work on it?
- Would your new employer let you work on it as part of your job?
- Do you have coauthors and/or students for whom it is important (for career reasons or otherwise)?
- Might it be valuable to your future career path, or help you keep open an option to return to academia?

But you can leave your current department out of the analysis.  The "benefits" that a published paper provides to a department are pretty minimal to begin with, and drop to near zero if the author is no longer at the institution.  (For instance, they can't really point to it as "great work our faculty are doing" if you're no longer on the faculty.)  So they really won't be impacted by your decision one way or the other.

Comment: And will you have enough time in your free time? is also a question one should consider.